# Ansible: Increment count in play recap for failed tasks when using ignore_errors

Tags: ansible

I am trying to not only use ansible as a configuration tool, but being able to perform mass validation checks across a series of severs easily.

As such, I am grabbing a bunch of different pieces of information at the beginning of the playbook, and then performing checks against them.

Seeing as these are validation checks and not configurations, I want all of my failures at once, rather than getting one, the playbook failing, having to address it and then run it again, over and over to find my multiple failures.

I am able to continue running the playbook by putting an ignore_errors flag into it, but it does not increment the "failed" count at the end of the playbook, and I would rather not have users have to scroll up through all of the output to look for red text, or scrape the logs to see if there was an error, especially seeing as there is a counter right at the end that works as a perfect at a glance reference.

I am using version Ansible 2.4.2.0, on Ubuntu version 14.04

Here is my playbook:

```
- name: Validates Preship configuration
  hosts:
    - active
    - dr
  become_user: root
  become: true
  become_method: su
  roles:
    - preShipValidation
  ignore_errors: yes
```

And then after importing tasks into a main.yml file, and running a separate task to populate my host_vars, I run the following task:

```
- name: BIOS Version Check for Equus or Seneca 2000/2100
  assert:
    that:
      - '"2.0a" in dmidecode_bios_ver.stdout'
  when: '"2000" in appliance_model and
         "X10DRW" in motherboard_model'
```

Which when ran will get me the following output (edited for easier reading)

```
TASK [preShipValidation : BIOS Version Check for Equus or Seneca 2000/2100] ******************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [server1] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
skipping: [server2] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
fatal: [server3]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "\"2.0a\" in dmidecode_bios_ver.stdout",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false
}
...ignoring
ok: [server4] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
server1                  : ok=11   changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0
server2                  : ok=12   changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0
server3                  : ok=10   changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0
server4                  : ok=11   changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Any ideas on how to get that failed count to show the errors it ignored?

Comment: Make your own callback plugin that handles `v2_runner_on_failed` and print your own statistics with `v2_playbook_on_stats`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the official answer for this is "install 2.8" (to be fair, this had not been written into the code until months after I asked the question).  One of the developers acknowledged this as is a bug:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27160

And checking the release notes for 2.8, there is definitely a commit in there for it.  I pulled the relevant code snippets, and put them in place to test it and it seemed to do the trick.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.8/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.8.rst#id6
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/48418

So thank you Konstantin for the tip, I started looking in this direction, but due to my limitation of python knowledge and how all of the code worked, I was having a tough time pulling together a callback for it (but learned some good stuff in the process!)

And thanks Pavan for the suggestion, but with this playbook there is hundreds of tasks already, so putting one of these in for every time i want to skip a task due to failure would have been tough to scale. And the real goal was to have it in the play recap, not just as another task so that the output is all together.

Answer (score 0):

In every task you are ignoring, save the output to a variable by using register tag and create an extra task that increments a variable by 1 if the registered variable's failed option is True.

Ex:

```
- name: Yum update
  yum:
    name: "*"
    state: latest
  register: result
  ignore_errors: True      

- name: Increment variable
  set_fact: failed_count={{ failed_count | int + 1 }}
  when: result.failed
```

Note this failed_count variable should be initialised to 0 in the beginning of playbook.